# WebRTC with ReactJS and Socket.io doesn't show Remote Stream

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webrtc, stun, simplewebrtc

I am trying to make a Zoom-like video call app with ReactJS and Socket.io using WebRTC.I am using NodeJS(socket.io) as the signaling server.
I have gone through the process of creating an offer and making the answer.The connection is in stable state. I get the media stream from the remote peer and add it to the video element but for some reason the video doesn't show up in the  element. Only the grey screen. Following is my code

ReactJS code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { socket } from '../socket';

const PC = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [{urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}] });

export function VideoPlayer () {
  const localVideoRef = useRef(null)
  const videoRef = useRef(null)
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  async function setStream(peerConnection) {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
    localVideoRef.current.srcObject = stream
    PC.addStream(stream);
  }

  const onAddStream = obj => {
    let vid = document.createElement('video');
    vid.setAttribute('class', 'video-small');
    vid.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    vid.setAttribute('muted', 'muted');
    vid.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous')
    vid.setAttribute('id', 'video-small');

    document.getElementById('users-container').appendChild(vid)
    vid.src = obj.stream
  }

  const handleAddUsers = data => {
    setUsers(data.users)
  }

  const createOffer = async id => {
    const offer = await PC.createOffer()

    await PC.setLocalDescription(offer)

    socket.emit('make-offer', {
      offer: offer,
      to: id
    })
  }

  const handleOffer = data => {
    const offer = data.offer

    PC.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer), async () => {
      
      const answer = await PC.createAnswer()
      await PC.setLocalDescription(answer)

      socket.emit('make-answer', {
        answer: answer,
        to: data.socket
      })
    })
  }

  const handleAnswer = data => {
    const answer = data.answer
    
    PC.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer), async () => {
      document.getElementById(data.socket).setAttribute('class', 'active');
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    PC.onaddstream = onAddStream
    setStream(PC)

    socket.on('add-users', handleAddUsers)
    socket.on('offer-made', handleOffer)
    socket.on('answer-made', handleAnswer)
    window.addEventListener("iceconnectionstatechange", (event) => {
      console.log(event)
    });

    return () => {
      PC.onaddstream = null
      socket.off('add-users', handleAddUsers)
      socket.off('offer-made', handleOffer)
      socket.off('answer-made', handleAnswer)
    }

  }, [])

  return(
    <div className='container'>
      <video style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }} id='localVideo' ref={localVideoRef} autoPlay muted />
      <div className='users-container' id='users-container'>
        <h4>Users</h4>
        <div id='users'>
          {users.map(id => (
            <div id={id} onClick={() => createOffer(id)}>{id}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The styles applied to the above code are as follows

```
html, body {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

video {
background: #CCC;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
}

.video-large {
width: 75%;
float: left;
}

.users-container {
width: 21%;
float: left;
padding: 2%;
position: relative;
}

.video-small {
margin-top: 20px;
width: 100%;
}

#users div {
color: red;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: pointer;
}

#users .active {
color: #000;
cursor: default;
}
```

And finally the relevant NodeJS code (signaling server)

```
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000"
  }
})

const clients = [];

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.emit('add-users', {
    users: clients
  })

  socket.broadcast.emit('add-users', {
    users: [socket.id]
  })

  socket.on('make-offer', function (data) {
    socket.to(data.to).emit('offer-made', {
      offer: data.offer,
      socket: socket.id
    });
  });

  socket.on('make-answer', function (data) {
    socket.to(data.to).emit('answer-made', {
      socket: socket.id,
      answer: data.answer
    });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket.id), 1);
    io.emit('remove-user', socket.id);
  });


  clients.push(socket.id)
})
```

What i am thinking is the issue might be with **iceconnectionstate**, as i have added an event listener on **iceconnectionstatechange** and it never moves on from **new** state. But i am not sure how to resolve that or even if that is an issue

Comment: If you ever find yourself manipulating the DOM with `document.createElement` in React, you are doing it wrong. Considering that, it could be the source of your problem. React might be re-rendering your component and creating multiple `video` elements with that, so your stream might get lost there.

Comment: @eventHandler what do you suggest is the alternative to `document.createElement` which i can use here ? `React.createElement` ? but i think i was having issue with setting the src on the element created with `React.createElement`

Comment: You should create a separate component for the video element. You can create a regular component that receives the stream as a property, or create a component with [forwardRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef) to forward the video element to the parent component.